# Why won't this Navigation Drawer open?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I have a simple login page, where one-half of the page is occupied by 2 `EditText` and a `Button`, and second half by a `ListFragment` displaying the public projects. I have made a separate class for Navigation Drawer so that in the future I can display this Navigation Drawer on every activity. Here is the code for **DrawerActivity.java:**

```
public class DrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private String mActivityTitle;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(DrawerActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {


        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }


        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };


    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }


    // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends DrawerActivity {

AutoCompleteTextView email;
EditText password;
Button submit;

String getEmail, getPassword;

public static HttpClient httpClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    email = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.get_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.get_password);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_register);

    Fragment fr = new PublicProjectsFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.publicProjectFragment, fr).commit();

    /*Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/titillium.otf");
    email.setTypeface(customFont);
    password.setTypeface(customFont);*/

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getEmail = email.getText().toString();
            getPassword = password.getText().toString();
            new HttpHandler().execute();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class HttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = "http://canvasflip.com/protected/actions/user.php?action=login";
        String responseStr = "";
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginId", getEmail));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", getPassword));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
            final String jsonResult = jsonObject.getString("result");
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (jsonResult.equals("success")) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProjectListActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder loginFailAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        loginFailAlert.setTitle("Login Failed");
                        loginFailAlert.setMessage("Wrong e-mail address or password, please enter again").setCancelable(false).
                                setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        email.setText("");
                                        password.setText("");
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = loginFailAlert.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectListFragment.java:** The class that displays the `ListFragment`

```
public class PublicProjectsFragment extends ListFragment {
String[] projectTitle;
String[] projectImage;

CustomAdapter adapter;

private List<RowItem> rowItems;

String imgUrl = "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/elements/userElements/";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_public_projects,null, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    projectTitle = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.projectTitle);
    projectImage = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.publicProjectPreview);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for(int i=0; i<projectTitle.length; i++) {
        String url = imgUrl+projectImage[i]+".png";
        RowItem item = new RowItem(projectTitle[i], url);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
        case 0: intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayBack.class);
            intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=694");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 1: intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayBack.class);
            intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=696");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 2: intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayBack.class);
            intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=697");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 3: intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayBack.class);
            intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=777");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#eeeeee"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="testapi@canvasflip.com"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:id="@+id/get_email" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="canvas123"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/get_password"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:text="@string/login_register"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:id="@+id/login_register"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="@color/DarkGrey"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

   <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.example.amangrover.myapp.PublicProjectsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/publicProjectFragment"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**drawer_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days , trying to figure out myself, searching google , but still no luck. The navigation drawer just won't open either by clicking the hamburger icon or by sliding from left. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In your main activity the navigation drawer layout doesn't exists

Comment: So in main activity, how can I set the navigation drawer? Sorry , just started learning android a week back,still a noob.

Comment: I'm building the answer, ina few minutes i publish it ;-)

Comment: take a look at new `NavigationView` by googles design library http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine thanks a lot! I'll try it and will let you know :)

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar will certainly check that out too. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `NavigationDrawer`, you have tu use `DrawerLayout` everywhere you need/want to use.

If you want to use it in the main activity, you have to build its layout like following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Here put your acrivity layout, 
for example the layout that you build in the main_activity.xml-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <!-- other objects -->

    </LinearLayout>


<!-- Here put the navigation drawer layout -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Suggestion: In the `DrawerActicity`, instead of `onCreate()`, i usually use `onStart()`, for example like follwing:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        //Here you call the initial methods
mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

addDrawerItems();
setupDrawer();


getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

In the Activity that extends `DrawerActivity`, you use the `onCreate()`, setting htbe layout etcc.

Doc reference: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Hope it's clear and helpful!

Comment: So where ever I want to use `NavigationDrawer` , I have to use `<android.support.v4.widget.Drawerlayout>` tags in all of those activities?

Comment: yes, i added at the answer a reference to the documentation

Comment: Thank you! I read the documentation , still missed this, now I feel how noob this question is.

Comment: Alternatively, you can transform all your top level Activities into Fragments, so your MainActivity will only contain the DrawerLayout and menu logic which swaps Fragments in the fragment container.

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine 1 more question, do I have to make a separate layout file for the navigation drawer? or I just have to include nav drawer's tag in every view I want the nav drawer to be visible?

Comment: Do you mean to use XML tag `<include>`?

Comment: What I am doing is, `setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout)` to set the layout in DrawerActivity.java. Do I have to make a separate file `drawer_layout.xml` ? Because I am getting an empty list. here is my new   question: [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456623/navigation-drawer-listview-is-empty). May be you can help.

Comment: I'm answering, hope it will help